Blur filter not showing Transform widget based on angle
In the following code nothing is displayed if the angle of the innermost Transform widget is -90 deg:
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as vm;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
              ..rotateX(vm.radians(20))
              ..rotateY(vm.radians(-30)),
            child: Stack(children: [
              Transform(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateX(vm.radians(-90)), // (1) Change this angle
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned.fill(
                child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
                  child: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

If I change the angle to -91, the blurred widget is displayed. If the blur filter is removed (by removing the Positioned widget), the rectangle is displayed. How can I get the blurred widget to display if the angle is -90?

I've come to the conclusion that using ImageFilter.blur the way I'm doing it does not work in Flutter. Even wrapping the grey Container in my answer with a ImageFiltered widget and not using BackdropFilter does not work.
However, my goal is to have a rectangle with blurry edges in order to simulate a shadow. I can achieve this by using BoxDecoration for the Container widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as vm;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
              ..rotateX(vm.radians(20))
              ..rotateY(vm.radians(-30)),
            child: Transform(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..rotateX(vm.radians(-90)),
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 200,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      blurRadius: 10,
                      spreadRadius: 0.5,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

